# Sed and dollar sign

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

"The Unix Programming Environment" states that '$' used in regular expression in sed means end-of-the line which is fine for me, because

```
cat file | sed 's/$/\n/'
```

is interpretted as "add newline at the end of each line".

The question arises, when I try to use the command:

```
cat file | sed '$d'
```

Shouldn't this line remove each line instead of the last one? In this context, dollar sign means end of the LAST line. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `regex` in sed must be  inside the delimiters(`;`,`:`, `~`, etc) other than quotes.

```
/regex/
```

ex:

```
sed '/foo/s/bar/bux/g' file
```

or

```
~regex~
```

ex:

```
sed 's~dd~s~' file
```

but not `'regex'`. So `$` in `'$d'` won't be considered as regex by sed. `'$d'` acts like an address which points out the last line.

Answer (score 7):

`$` is treated as regex anchor when used in pattern in `s` command e.g.

```
s/$/\n
```

However in `$d`, `$` is **not** a regex anchor, it is address notation that means the **last line** of the input, which is deleted using the `d` command.

Also note that `cat` is unnecessary in your last command. It can be used as:

```
sed '$d' file
```

Answer (score 5):

In the second usage, there is no regular expression. The `$` there is an address, meaning the last line.