# sed command with dollar

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to understand a shell script which uses the command below:

```
sed '$d;1,2 d;s/^ //' $file1 > $file2
```

I figured `s/^ //` gets rid of blank lines, but cannot make out what the `$d;1,2 d;` does. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Strictly, the `s/^ //` part eliminates one leading blank from each line that starts with a blank.  That's not the same as deleting blank lines.  That would be done with `/^[[:blank:]]*$/d` or an equivalent command.

Comment: When in doubt, and there's no time for asking, sometimes it helps to run some known data through mystery code, just to see what happens.  Piping in a list of numbers, like `seq 10 | sed '$d;1,2 d'` would have helped there, the output being *3* through *9*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to understand dollar sign ($) in sed script programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224326/how-to-understand-dollar-sign-in-sed-script-programming)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is deleting the last line of the file and the first two lines.

The `sed` 'd'elete command is expecting one or two arguments.  If one, then the delete will happen for that line; if two, then the delete will happen from the line matching the first argument through the line matching the second.  The arguments can be regular expressions, or line numbers.  `sed` also recognizes `$` for the last line.

So the `$d` is deleting the last line. and `1,2d` is deleting the 1st through 2nd lines.

See `man sed` for all the gory details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: `info sed` for **aaaaaall** the gory details ;)